# Expectation of "{" errors? Along with expected unspecified ID erros?

Tags: c++

Okay I know this is more text than you want but I literally cannot find the problem in the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

int main(void)
{
   int score1, score2;

   PrintInfo() ;

   score1 = GetScore(); //  Call function GetScore, to obtain a value for score1.

   if (RangeError()) ;  //  IF score1 is out of range, print an error message.
   {
       cout << "Sorry you entered an invalid score." << endl ;
   }
   else  // THIS IS LINE 46, THIS IS THE ELSE IT IS TALKING ABOUT
   {
       score2 = Getscore ; // Call GetScore a second time, to obtain a value for score2.

       if (RangeError ()); // IF score2 is out of range, print an error message.
       {
           cout << "Sorry you entered an invalid score." << endl ;
       }
       else  // ELSE, using a call to function maximum within a cout
       {     // statement, print the maximum score.
           cout << maximum() << endl ;
       }
   }

    return 0;
}
```

There's a lot in there, I know, but the main problem seems to be around my second else. For whatever reason I keep getting the following errors:

lab05a.cpp:46: error: expected `}' before 'else'

lab05a.cpp: At global scope:

lab05a.cpp:46: error: expected unqualified-id before 'else'

I know it's something to do with bracketing but I can't find any problems! Also: I apologize for the lack of line numbers, we are not using an editor that allows them. I could have added them, but I removed a lot of irrelevant text for brevity and adding them on would not have given them the proper line number for the error. As such I will show where line 46 is. I removed most of the declarations since the problem does not seem to lie therein. Please help me, this is the first time I've ever had a problem I couldn't solve on my own.

Comment: You have a semicolon after your if. Also, you don't seem to be calling `GetScore()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (RangeError()) ;
{
```

should be

```
if (RangeError())
{
```

Comment: OH NOW I GET WHY. Thank you very much.

Comment: Where would be more recommended to go then? I would have never noticed that error on my own, I would have kept pouring over my book and notes and never found it. I have now learned to look for something I previously thought to be correct. The only penance I am capable of completing is to answer some very pitiful questions on my own -- Which I will proceed to do when done with this program.

Comment: @user1764081: You could either read a book, or reduce your existing code until you've isolated the error, and then make *very* simple test programs to prove to yourself that you understand each ingredient part of the code separately. Per aspera ad astras.

Comment: I was reading my book and making fast headway to nowhere. Thank you for your time.